# Sorted Data Structure with index retrieval

Tags: java, collections

Which Collection stores data in some specified order and can return or set elements according to index? I know that TreeSet implements SortedSet, hence stores data according to either natural ordering or some Comparator object provided by the programmer. But I don't know how to retrieve or set elements in a TreeSet using index. On the other hand, ArrayList and some other structures can be used to retrieve or set their elements accoring to any index. But they don't store elements in sorted order. Any way to have both features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and sort it using [`Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). If you have to insert elements, you can find the insertion-point using [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29), giving you O(log n) complexity for insertions (as opposed to O(n log n) for resorting). `ArrayList` provides an [overload of `add` that takes a position parameter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29).

Comment: I have to add elements far too many times. So each time i have to call sort() because I need to have the structure sorted at all times without fail. That would be ok right?

Comment: You do not have to resort. If you use binary search to find the correct insertion-point, you can insert your items so that they are always in the correct order. This will give you the same complexity as a `TreeSet`.

Comment: inserting into the middle of ArrayList causese copying elements, so it's not an O(log n) operation. consider LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Populate elements into ArrayList and sort it by calling 
Collections.sort().

Comment: I have to add elements far too many times. So each time i have to call sort() because I need to have the structure sorted at all times without fail.

Comment: can you extend ArrayList and create your own datastructure?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at indexed-tree-map https://github.com/geniot/indexed-tree-map I enhanced TreeMap to provide access and retrieval by index.
To get the insertion index of a key which doesn't exist you can try to run the put-entryIndex-remove sequence. Although it may not be very efficient for your requirements. My entryIndex implementation is based on first finding the entry and then calculating its index. I will take a look if it can be improved for non-existing keys.

You can't set elements by index in a sorted set without breaking accidentally the sorting order. If you mean 'setting values of a map by key's index' then again you can use index-tree-map. Just find the key by index and use put to overwrite the value.